# Understanding Keane and Petersen's proof of Maximal Ergodic Theorem

Tags: proof-explanation, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

The proof is from *[Easy and nearly simultaneous proofs of the ergodic theorem and maximal ergodic theorem](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0608251.pdf)* (Keane, Petersen, 2006).

Let $(X, \mathcal B, \mu)$ be a probability space, $T:X\to X$ be a measure-preserving map, $f\in L^1(X, \mathcal B, \mu)$. Let
$$A_k f = \frac 1 k \sum_{j = 0}^{k-1} f \circ T^j, f^*_N = \sup_{1\le k \le N} A_k f,$$

Take $\lambda \in L^1(X)$, then let $E_N = \{f_N^* > \lambda\}$, then since $f \le f_N^*$, we have that $\forall x \notin \{f_N^* > \lambda\}$, 
$$[(f - \lambda)\chi_{E_N}](x) = 0 \ge (f - \lambda)(x) $$

Thus $(f - \lambda)\chi_{E_N} \ge (f - \lambda)$

Then we consider a sum, where $m$ is a big but undetermined integer.
$$\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} (f - \lambda )\chi_{E_N}(T^kx)$$

This is where the first part of the second page starts, and I don't know what it means.

> There is maybe an initial string of $0$’s during which $T^k x \notin E_N$ . Then there is a first time $k$ when $T^k x \in E_N$, which initiates a string of no more than $N$ terms, the sum of which is positive (using on each of these terms the fact that $(f − λ)\chi_{E_N} ≥ (f − λ))$.

From definition of $E_N$, we have that $\forall T^k x \in E_N,$ $\exists 1\le l \le N, $

$$f(T^k x) + f(T^{k+1} x) + \cdots f(T^{k+l-1}x) \ge l \lambda(T^k x)$$
thus 
$$[(f-\lambda) + (f\circ T - \lambda) + \cdots (f\circ T^{l-1} - \lambda)](T^k x) \ge 0$$

However, Keane seems to want me to show that

$$[(f-\lambda) + (f - \lambda)\circ T + \cdots (f - \lambda)\circ T^{l-1}](T^k x) \ge 0$$

> using the fact that $(f − λ)\chi_{E_N} ≥ (f − λ))$.

I can't see how that's possible. Not to mention that $(f − λ)\chi_{E_N} ≥ (f − λ))$ is true over all of $X$, not just over $E_N$, so "using the fact" seems uselessly unspecific.

Comment: $(f\circ T^j-\lambda) = (f-\lambda) \circ T^j$. This is just trivially always true

Comment: @mathworker21 No. $(f\circ T^j-\lambda)(x) = f( T^j(x))-\lambda (x) \neq f (T^j (x)) - \lambda (T^j (x))$

Comment: I'm pretty sure $\lambda$ is just supposed to be a real number.

Comment: @mathworker21 Yes. Still won't work.

Comment: wut? if $\lambda$ is a real number, then $\lambda(x) = \lambda(T^j(x)) = \lambda$....

Comment: @mathworker21 $λ(x)\neq λ(T^j(x))$ if $x\neq T^j(x)$

Comment: $\lambda$ is a real number!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! both things are just $\lambda$

Comment: @mathworker21 Actually if you look at the question, it says merely $\lambda \in L^1(X)$. It's not a constant function.

Comment: Dude, what is your problem. I first said that I think $\lambda$ is supposed to be a real number (constant function) instead of an arbitrary $L^1$ function. Then you said "Still won't work", which is false as I explained by saying "if $\lambda$ is a real number, then $\lambda(x) = \lambda(T^j(x)) = \lambda$". And then you incorrectly objected again. I hope you realize that $\lambda(x) = \lambda(T^j(x))$ if $\lambda$ is constant. And once again, I think in the question, $\lambda$ is supposed to be a constant instead of an arbitrary $L^1$ function.

Comment: @mathworker21 You confused me with the claim that $\lambda$ is a real number. If $\lambda$ is constant, then you are right. But it's not in the paper, or in the question I asked.

Comment: In the theorem statement, it says $\lambda$ is invariant. So $\lambda(x) = \lambda(T^j(x))$.

Comment: @mathworker21 Thanks. This is correct, and there's no more problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$[(f-\lambda) + (f\circ T - \lambda) + \cdots (f\circ T^{l-1} - \lambda)](T^k x) \ge 0$ and $[(f-\lambda) + (f - \lambda)\circ T + \cdots (f - \lambda)\circ T^{l-1}](T^k x) \ge 0$ are equivalent (almost everywhere), since in the theorem it's assumed that $\lambda$ is invariant under $T$: ($\lambda\circ T = \lambda$ a.e.) function.